# What is the equivalent of trancount in Postrgesql?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, plpgsql

In sqlserver, there is a stored procedure like below. If this sp executes with another transaction ( ex: by another sp executes this sp), COMMIT/ROLLBACK doesnt work as desired(@@TRANCOUNT<>0). Also, if @@TRANCOUNT = 0 it will execute COMMIT or ROLLBACK in respect to  @var1 value.

I have created a sp in postrgesql for same purpose but couldnt find an equivalent to use
"IF  @@TRANCOUNT = 0 " in postgresql.Is there any equivalent method for this statement?

Note: It looks there is no direct equivalent code for trancount.
Is there any solution for the case below?

> Case: sp1(mainsp) executes sp2(childsp). If sp2 rollback due to var1=1
> , it rollbacks all sp1 previous statements without trancount. How
> could i handle this?

sample code:

```
   create PROCEDURE [sp2]          
            (       
            @id1 INT ,      
            @output1 INT = 0 OUTPUT      
            )      
        AS      
    BEGIN       
        SET output1 = 0         
          
        DECLARE @trancnt INT 
        SET @trancnt = 0 
        DECLARE @var1 INT
        SET @var1 = 0
             
            IF  @@TRANCOUNT = 0  
            BEGIN  
                SET @trancnt = 1 
                BEGIN TRANSACTION 
            END              
      
            insert into table2
            values(1,2)
            
            select top 1 @var1 = j.col1 from table1
                            
            IF @var1=1 then
            BEGIN
            IF @trancnt = 1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            output1=-3
            END 
            
            IF @var1<>1 then
            BEGIN
            IF @trancnt = 1 COMMIT TRANSACTION
            output1=1
            END 
                    
    END
```

Comment: [https://www.postgresql-archive.org/equivalent-of-TRANCOUNT-PostgreSQL-td6201400.html#a6201440](https://www.postgresql-archive.org/equivalent-of-TRANCOUNT-PostgreSQL-td6201400.html#a6201440)

Comment: T-SQL needs `@@TRANCOUNT` due to its lack of support for true nested transactions, and its arcane error handling where transactions may or may not be aborted/doomed depending on the nature and severity of the error. I have no experience with error handling in Postgres, but I'd be very surprised if it's in any way equivalent. I propose you simply unconditionally start a transaction and commit or rollback as necessary, i.e. write the code the obvious way.

Comment: There is no @@TRANCOUNT in PostgreSQL because the concept of nested transactions does not exists in PostGreSQL and there is no equivalent. This is a severe limitation of PostGreSQL. See more limitations of PG in this paper: http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/

Comment: The concept of nested transactions does not exist in T-SQL either; it just pretends they're supported by incrementing `@@TRANCOUNT`. If true nested transactions were supported, you could `ROLLBACK` a nested transaction without affecting the overall work, but this is not possible. Oracle is an example of an RDBMS that supports this.

Comment: Case:  sp1(mainsp) executes sp2(childsp).   If sp2 rollback due to var1=1 , it rollbacks all sp1 previous statements without trancount. How could i handle this?